# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined in Vue with Typescript & Webpack,

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router, vue-loader

I get following error when click on "Counter" or "Fetch Data".

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.                      vendor.js?v=MxNIG8b0Wz6QtAfWhyA0-4CCwZshMscBGmtIBXxKshw:13856 

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <T> at ClientApp\components\app\app.vue.html
         <Root>
```

My boot.ts is as following:

```
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Counter = () => import('./components/counter/counter').then(m => m.default);
const FetchData = () => import('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata');

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component:  require('./components/home/home.vue.html').default },
    { path: '/counter', component: Counter },
    { path: '/fetchdata', component: FetchData }
];

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html').default)
});
```

My Counter.vue.html is as following

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Counter</h1>

        <p>This is a simple example of a Vue.js component.</p>

        <p>Current count: <strong>{{ currentcount }}</strong></p>

        <button @click="incrementCounter">Increment</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./counter.ts"></script>
```

My counter.ts is as following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class CounterComponent extends Vue {
    currentcount: number = 0;

    incrementCounter() {
        this.currentcount++;
    }
}
```

My fetchdata.vue.html is as following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Weather forecast</h1>

        <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

        <table v-if="forecasts.length" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                    <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in forecasts">
                    <td>{{ item.dateFormatted }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.temperatureC }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.temperatureF }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.summary }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <p v-else><em>Loading...</em></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./fetchdata.ts"></script>
```

My fetchdata.ts is as following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

interface WeatherForecast {
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}

@Component
export default class FetchDataComponent extends Vue {
    forecasts: WeatherForecast[] = [];

    mounted() {
        fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<WeatherForecast[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.forecasts = data;
            });
    }
}
```

My NPM packags are as following:

-- vue-loader@14.2.2

-- vue@2.5.16

-- vue-router@3.0.1

-- webpack@4.3.0    (npm list webpack shows **-- (empty)**. dont know why. But this is not an issue I guess.)

-- typescript@2.8.1

Comment: did you try to import your `Counter` and `FetchData` components just using *import*?
`import Counter from './components/counter/counter'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetchdata, u'll also need to do what you have done for 'counter'.

```
const FetchData = () => import('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata').then(m => m.default);
```

Then, for both of the component. U have called **".ts"** files which knows nothing aboout **where their ".vue.html"** files (templates) are.

shortest resolution is to refer ".vue.html" where you have referenced their ".ts" files. like this.

```
const FetchData = () => import('./components/fetchdata/fetchdata.vue.html').then(m => m.default);

const Counter= () => import('./components/counter/counter.vue.html').then(m => m.default);
```